# UISwitchがonの時は”１”　offの時は"0"にしたい

Tags: ios, swift

下記のコードはビルドは失敗してしまいます。
UISwitchがonの時、変数firstの値は１、offの時は0にしたいのですが、方法がわかいりません。

ご教授願います。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var first: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // SwitchのOn/Off切り替わりの際に、呼ばれるイベントを設定する.
        first.addTarget(self, action: "onClickMySwicth:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}
        internal func onClickMySwicth(sender: UISwitch){
        if sender.on { print("1")}
        else { print("0")}
        }
}
```

ビルドの途中で、下記のようなエラー表示が出ます。
ご教授お願いします。

2016-02-05 21:11:37.598 139[607:8643] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_39.ViewController 0x7fb1d1c2ef60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ferst.'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010436de65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165

    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001060addeb objc_exception_throw + 48

    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010436daa9 -[NSException raise] + 9

    3   Foundation                          0x00000001047369bb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288

    4   UIKit                               0x0000000104d19320 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88

    5   UIKit                               0x0000000104f47f41 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109

    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042ae4a0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224

    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104f46924 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864

    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104d1feea -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381

    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104d20816 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178

    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104d20b74 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138

    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104d212e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27

    12  UIKit                               0x0000000104bf7ab0 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61

    13  UIKit                               0x0000000104bf8199 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282

    14  UIKit                               0x0000000104c09c2e -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42

    15  UIKit                               0x0000000104b82663 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131

    16  UIKit                               0x0000000104b88cc6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760

    17  UIKit                               0x0000000104b85e7b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188

    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000107f42754 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192

    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000107f42ac2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45

    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104299a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010428f95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010428ee13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010428e828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000104b857cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000104b8a610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    26  139                                 0x00000001041904cd main + 109
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106bb692d start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の変更で、ビルドできます。

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ferst: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // SwitchのOn/Off切り替わりの際に、呼ばれるイベントを設定する.
        ferst.addTarget(self, action: "onClickMySwicth:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    internal func onClickMySwicth(sender: UISwitch){
        if sender.on { print("1")}
        else { print("0")}
    }

}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。}を一箇所落としていました。追加してみましたが、ビルドはできませんでした。
if sender.on { 以降の書き方がマズいのだと思いますが、どうすれば、onとoffを切り替えられるのか？を教えて下さい。お願いします。

Comment: 私の環境だと、ビルドと実行まで確認できています。
ビルドできない、ということは、その原因となるエラーを、Xcodeが表示しているはずですので、それを追記していただくと解決方法が見つかりそうです。

Comment: 本文にエラーメッセージを載せました。
お願いします。

Comment: 正確には、ビルドはできますが、シミュレーターを展開している途中でクラッシュします。

Comment: それは普通ビルドエラーとは言わないですね。ビルドエラーはコンパイル時やリンク時などの実行前に起こるエラーを言います。エラーの原因は、書いてある通りで、ferstという変数の名前をfirstに変えたので、Storyboard でもともとバインドされていたferstが見つからない、というエラーです。

Comment: おーーーーー！できました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

エラーの内容を見る限りコードではなくStoryboardに問題があります。
UISwitchから引っ張ってferstという変数とコードを関連づけた。しかし、ferstがタイポしていることに気づきfirst書き直したのではないでしょうか？問題はコード上でタイポを修正してもStoryboardには自動的に反映されていないことにあります。Storyboardにはferstと関連付いていることになっており、存在しない変数にアクセスできず落ちています。

Storyboardのferstとの関連を外してfirstと関連づけ直すことで解決します。

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。仰る通り、ファーストをferstと間違って変数にした後、firstが正しいことに気づきコードのみを修正した結果でした。ありがとうございました。